# Case statement help

Tags: bash, shell-script, case

I am quite new to Unix and I need help with this case statement.
What I want to do is to make the user select a variable with a case statement and then make the system read the result of the choice made by the user.
Here is my script structure (as an example):

```bsh
CHOOSEfruit () {
clear
echo "Choose fruit you need to buy (a.Apple b.Banana c.Pear d.Pineapple)"
read FRUIT
case $FRUIT in
    a|A)
    echo "Apple"
    ;;
    b|B)
    echo "Banana"
    ;;
    c|C)
    echo "Pear"
    ;;
    d|D)
    echo "Pineapple"
    ;;
esac
clear
echo "The fruit you need to buy is $FRUIT"
echo ""
read -p "Press [Enter] key to go back to main menu"
clear
}
```

If I choose "a", I want my script to output: "The fruit you need to buy is Apple"

Answer (score 5):

This would be better solved by a `select` loop:

```bsh
PS3='Please select fruit from the menu: '

select fruit in 'No fruit please' Apple Banana Pear Pineapple; do
    case $REPLY in
        1)
            # User wants no fruit
            unset fruit
            break
            ;;
        [2-5])
            # All ok, exit loop
            break
            ;;
        *)
            # Invalid choice
            echo 'Try again' >&2
    esac
done

if [ -n "$fruit" ]; then
    printf 'The fruit you need is %s\n' "$fruit"
else
    echo 'You selected no fruit!'
fi
```

The `select` loop presents a list of choices to a user in an interactive menu.  The prompt given to the user for selecting an item from the menu is the string in `$PS3`.

In the body of the `select` loop, the value in `$fruit` will be the actual text string that the user selected, while `$REPLY` will be whatever the user typed at the prompt.

Note that there is no need to use a `case ... esac` statement in the loop.  You could use any code here. For example, you may feel more comfortable using `if ... then ... elif ... else ... fi`:

```
if [ "$REPLY" = 1 ]; then
    unset fruit
    break
elif [[ $REPLY == [2-5] ]]; then
    break
else
    echo 'Try again' >&2
fi
```

The `select` loop is exited with `break`, just like any other infinite loop.

Three runs of this code:

```
$ bash script
1) No fruit please
2) Apple
3) Banana
4) Pear
5) Pineapple
Please select fruit from the menu: 1
You selected no fruit!
```

```
$ bash script
1) No fruit please
2) Apple
3) Banana
4) Pear
5) Pineapple
Please select fruit from the menu: 2
The fruit you need is Apple
```

```
$ bash script
1) No fruit please
2) Apple
3) Banana
4) Pear
5) Pineapple
Please select fruit from the menu: 6
Try again
Please select fruit from the menu: 3
The fruit you need is Banana
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost got it right. Simply edit your case statement like this:

```bsh
case $FRUIT in
    a|A)
    FRUIT="Apple"
    ;;
    b|B)
    FRUIT="Banana"
    ;;
    c|C)
    FRUIT="Pear"
    ;;
    d|D)
    FRUIT="Pineapple"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: This looks awkward (longwinded). Better with `FRUIT=${fruitmap[${REPLY^^}]}` where `$REPLY` is what the user is entering and `fruitmap` is an associative array of letter-to-fruit mappings. `declare -A fruitmap=( [A]=Apple [B]=Banana ... )`

Comment: I know there is room for improvement. I just wanted to let OP know what he missed in his solution. :)